# Visual Studio 2019 error when build WxWidgets app for 64 bit version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, wxwidgets

I use Visual Studio Community 2019 for Windows with WxWidgets 3.1.5. In "Developer Command Prompt fo VS 2019", I have built WxWidgets with

```
>nmake /f makefile.vc RUNTIME_LIBS=static BUILD=release TARGET_CPU=X86
>nmake /f makefile.vc RUNTIME_LIBS=static BUILD=debug TARGET_CPU=X86
>nmake /f makefile.vc RUNTIME_LIBS=static BUILD=release TARGET_CPU=X64
>nmake /f makefile.vc RUNTIME_LIBS=static BUILD=debug TARGET_CPU=X64
```

When I try to build an app with `/MT` and x86 debug or release configuration I have no errors, but when I try to build an app with x64 compiler both debug and release give me this error in the "types.h" file:

> Error E1256 __w64 can only be specified in int, long, and pointer types.

How can I fix it?

Comment: At a glance, it sounds like all of your targets are pointing at the same build of wxwidgets.

Comment: i don't know, actually i described the commands i used to build wxwidgets just because i thought they might be useful to understand the problem and fix it

Comment: What's more relevant is how you tell your app where wxwidgets is located.

Comment: I use an Enviroment Variable (WXWIN)

Comment: The error should be at line 374 of the "WXWIN\include\wx\types.h" file

Comment: @TheNemoNemesis, how did you build an application? It definitely sounds like it tries to use the same X86 target for both builds...

Comment: @Igor, I use the Visual Studio IDE and I build the application from the IDE itself

Comment: @drescherjm, I don't think that the error belong to the WxWidgets build because I had it also when I was using WxWidgets in my old PC, in where I built wxwidgets in a different way, I think that the error is caused by the build of the applications that uses WxWidgets

Comment: You may have to produce some type of minimal example. [mcve]

Comment: ok, if I understand what you are saying to me, you are asking me to give you the tools to reproduce the same error to find a way to solve it, give me 5 minutes and I will give you everything

Comment: @TheNemoNemesis, ok, so are you working off of the minimal sample sln file or you copied the properties file to the brand new solution? Also, please check the 64 bit configuration and make sure the include and lib folders are set correctly.

Comment: I'm working on a new solution where I copied all the properties of the project that gave me the initial error

Comment: Here is the download of the .ZIP file in which I copied all the files you need to duplicate my error: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-dN4JkQL561mvVLTj28g9mnKp3nXTbxn/view?usp=sharing"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after about 1,30 hours I've found the problem and I think i can find a solution, the problem is the WxWidgets build, for a certain reason that I don't realy understood, the libraries that should be compiled in 64 bit are instead compiled in 32 bit, I don't know if this is the real problem, but it could be still part of it. With some research I've found some error message like this that before were hidden: `"1> C: \ Downloaded_Libraries \ WxWidgets \ wxWidgets-3.1.5_Static \ lib \ vc_x64_lib \ wxmsw31ud_gl.lib: warning LNK4272: the 'x86' type of the library computer conflicts with the 'x64' type of the target computer"`

Comment: This error message says that the x64 lib is compiled in x86

Comment: ***I don't know if this is the real problem*** Yes its a real problem. This means you are mixing 32 and 64 bit. You can not do that so you need to use the correct wxWidgets binaries for your application. Meaning if your application is 32 bit your wxWidgets must be 32 bit. Same goes for x64.

Comment: @drescherjm, I know that, but I thought I have built the x64 libraries with the 64 bit configuration, but it sounds like I was wrong

Comment: The same happened to me. The problem was that I ran `nmake /f makefile.vc BUILD=release TARGET_CPU=X64` from a x86 command prompt. I ran this very same command from an x86_64 command prompt and the problem was solved.